# Tamper Data shortcut icon is huge

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, tamper-data

I am using a Firefox Extension called [Tamper Data Icon Redux](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data-icon-redux/reviews/?src=api). This extension allows me to quickly launch the **Tamper Data** extension tool, using a button conveniently located on the Firefox toolbar. Recently, the toolbar shortcut icon size seems to have grown much larger for no apparent reason. For reference, this icon used to be the same exact size as all the other toolbar icons.

Does anyone know why this is so large now, or more importantly, how to fix it?

[image: image showing the absurdly large icon]

Comment: Did you try to contact the addon author?

Comment: That would be my next step. I planned to see if any Stack Overflow users might have information first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

Go to about:addons, click the gear icon, and choose "Check for Updates". You should be all set.

Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: The icon has returned to normal size in the current version. Thanks!